# Как изменить MAC-header Ethernet пакета?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ethernet

С помощью библиотеки WinSock2, при получении данных я получаю только IP-пакет, а вот WireShark мне говорит, что там ещё присутствует MAC-header (MAC-dest MAC-source, Ethernet type). Вот и вопрос, какими средствами пользоваться, чтобы получить полный Ethernet-пакет, который мне пришел? Тоже самое касается и отправки любых данных. Задача состоит в том, чтобы я сам формировал Ethernet-frame.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой WinPcap.

Comment: Кстати, если вы в качестве MAC-адреса отправителя подставите адрес соседней машины, которая подключена к одному с вами коммутатору, то вы заблокируете ей доступ в сеть ;)

Comment: Ну, а код показать вы не хотите? Как вы создаёте объект сокета